# Query over firebase doesn't bring most recent values on cloud, but local on device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the firebase api as a database, and have the persistance enabled (this is mandatory, for I would like the user has the most recent information available offline).
The problem I'm facing right now is that when I make a query (wiht the query commands), the response I get is repsect with the local info of the device and never retrieve the info for the cloud.

How can I make to bring the info from the cloud when the user is online?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was making a observeSingleEventOfType and this only get the values of the devices. Once I changed to observeEventType it works!